# ActionBar (item) занимает много места

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как уменьшить размер `item'а` чтобы его размер был ограничен его содержанием?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_file"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_plus_1"
    android:title="Add..."
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_video2"
    android:title="Photo"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/photo_ic"/>
```

Вот так я его добавляю

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_file, menu);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое Title не помещается полностью в ActionBar из-за добавленного мною меню

Comment: Какого айтема? Не очень понятно, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавил более подробное описание проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете скрыть элементы меню непосредственно из Action Bar, задав их атрибутам `showAsAction` значение `never`.

В этом случае, элементы будут отображаться только в меню, которые вызывается по клику на троеточие и тогда места на панели будет больше, соответственно, для тайтла будет больше места.

Comment: но ведь сам элемент(иконка "+") занимает явно не столько места чтобы ограничивать видимость title

Comment: @Heaven, А, теперь понял о чем Вы. А что в тайтле написано? Как выглядит Action Bar, если убрать оба значка?

Comment: В Title написано  "Чат с врачом"

Comment: @Heaven, На устройстве, в инструментах разработчика включите показ границ элементов и покажите границы значков и тайтла.

Comment: Оказывается в динамически добавлял один пустой элемент динамически во время инициализации приложение и он везде отображался,спасибо, помогли разобраться:)